# How to tell an RxJS Observable timer to emit the next in sequence immediately

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have tried very hard to tell a RxJS timer to move onto the next sequence to no avail. Could someone please help me out with this one. I have busted my wits on how to do this. But have not managed it. Here is a sample of code explaining what I am trying to do. I have tried Subjects. I have No matter what I try it seems that you have to somehow throw the subscription away and restart, Even then how?? My comments in the code below should explain what I wish to achieve.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'testAngular4';
    private condition = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    timer(0, 15000).pipe(
      takeWhile((val) => {
      console.log('inside takeWhile', ' val is ', val);
      return val < 30000;
    })).subscribe(value1 => {
      console.log(' subject subscription value is ', value1);
      timer(300, 3000).subscribe((value2) => {
        // Do something here
        console.log(' inside inner timmer subscribe and value is ', value2);
        // How to tell the above timer to emit next value before the 3 seconds
        // have elapsed. This would obviously be based on some condition
        if (this.condition) {
          // Emit the next value in the inner timer sequence above.
          // I mean don't wait any longer - move on. Emit
        }
      });

      // How to tell the above timer to emit next value before the 3 seconds
      // have elapsed. This would obviously be based on some condition
      if (this.condition) {
        // Emit the next value in the outer timer sequence above
        // I mean don't wait any longer - move on. Emit
      }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: can you please describe what you are trying to achieve? With example. To emit sequence immediately you can use `startWith`

Comment: Hi -I already supplied the code above to show what I wish to do. But I will explain further. Imagine some code inside the subscription of the inner timer completes sooner than the delay time (3 seconds in this case) the timer was told in its constructor to allow to pass before it emits the next sequence. Under this situation I wish to tell the timer don't wait any longer. emit the next sequence. Say the code inside the subscription completes sooner than 3 seconds. Say 1 second. Don't want to wait another 2 seconds for the timer to emit again. I want to tell the timer to emit the next sequence.

Comment: First imho you should not do this in subscription. In subscription you get the final result. Second if you want to change to the new timer use `switchMap`. If this doesnt help can you provide example of what should be emitted when? In the best case using marble diagram.

Comment: How would I use the switchmap in my code above to change to the new timer please? I tried that and could not work out how to use a switchmap inside the subscription? Do you mean use a switchmap outside the subscription? Could you please provide a hint. I cannot post my work code but will try and improve my code above to elaborate further. But basically I want to stay in the subscription but to move on to the next emission. Thanks.

Comment: you cannot use operators inside the subscription. As i wrote - there is a final result in the subscription. So to use it in the observable chain see this example: `interval(2000).pipe(switchMap(() => interval(500)))`

Comment: Thanks Martin. Let me read and digest your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to emit an event after certain time interval in RxJS, you can evaluate throttleTime.

You can find a similar example in their documentation:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a look at the Rxjs throttleTime docs: Emits a value from the source Observable, then ignores subsequent source values for duration milliseconds, then repeats this process. I want to tell my Observable to emit the next sequence only and not repeat - one Off call every now and then. Can I still achieve that using throttleTime? I kinda of think maybe I can but the word repeat in the docs worries me.

Comment: On second thought. Having had a look at the operator throttleTime, I don't think this operator can achieve what I am trying to do but I can be wrong!